When exporting to HTML, how to make org-attach links relative (instead absolute path)?
* test                                                               :ATTACH:
:PROPERTIES:
:ID:       26fe8748-2986-4806-b3ef-137401ba27ca
:END:


[[attachment:test.png]]

[[file:data/26/fe8748-2986-4806-b3ef-137401ba27ca/test.png]]

When exporting above org-file (at /tmp/asdf.org) to HTML, the links to the images are exported like below
...
<div id="orge1cbcfc" class="figure">
<p><img src="file:///tmp/data/26/fe8748-2986-4806-b3ef-137401ba27ca/test.png" alt="test.png" />
</p>
</div>


<div id="org86c125c" class="figure">
<p><img src="data/26/fe8748-2986-4806-b3ef-137401ba27ca/test.png" alt="test.png" />
</p>
</div>
...

As you can see, [[attachment:test.png]] is exported as full path. So I worry that when I publish exported HTML onto different machine (with probably at different directory than my main computer) the links will get be broken.
So I'm asking, when exporting to HTML, how to make org-attach links relative (instead absolute path)?
Of course, I may have using wrong tool for wrong job, or asking wrong questions. Any other methods is welcome.

There is no option to convert absolute file paths to relative paths on export (despite the fact that the Org mode manual states: "For Org links to external files, the backend transforms the links to relative paths" - AFAICT, that is a documentation bug). OTOH, when you use org-publish, absolute file paths are converted to relative paths automatically. Since the data/ directory where (by default) attached files are found is a separate directory which, in general, will need to be copied when you publish an HTML project, the "real" solution is to use org-publish, not org-export.
But org-export is useful for small tests, where you don't want to set up a publishing project, so here's an explanation of how export works with attachment links.
The HTML exporter never sees attachment links: they are converted to file links before the Org file is parsed. That is done by org-attach-expand-links which is added to org-export-before-parsing-functions (a.k.a org-export-before-parsing-hook), a hook that is run by org-export on a copy of the Org buffer before that buffer is parsed for export.
The org-attach-expand-links function scans the whole buffer for attachment links and rewrites each such link as a file link by creating a new string, file:<path>, and replacing attachment:<file> with file:<path>. The <path> is constructed from the <file> by calling org-attach-expand on the latter: (org-attach-expand file) (see l. 788 of org-attach.el). Note that there is no provision for converting absolute paths to relative paths.
The following two sections implement two solutions: an org-publish one that requires additional configuration but no code changes, and an org-export one that requires code changes but makes your example work without any additional configuration.
Solution using org-publish
In the context of your example (a single file with a data directory for attachments in the same directory), a simple org-publish template looks as follows:
#+begin_src elisp :results drawer
  (let ((basedir "/tmp")
        (pubdir "~/public_html/test/"))
    (setq-local org-publish-project-alist
                `(("test" :components ("orgfiles" "other"))
                  ("orgfiles"
                   :base-directory ,basedir
                   :publishing-directory ,pubdir
                   :publishing-function org-html-publish-to-html)
                  ("other" 
                   :base-directory ,(concat basedir "data/")
                   :base-extension "jpg\\|gif\\|png"
                   :recursive t
                   :publishing-directory ,(concat pubdir "data/")
                   :publishing-function org-publish-attachment))))
          
#+end_src

Season to taste.
You can add the code block in a Code section and tag  it noexport. You can then evaluate the code block with C-c C-c to change the configuration. Note that it sets org-publish-project-alist locally in the buffer, so it does not affect any global setting. When you kill the buffer, the configuration goes away, so if you want to do it again, you'll need to re-evaluate the block before publishing.
You can then publish with M-x org-publish-project RET test RET and check the output in the publishing directory (which you can adjust as you wish - ditto for the basedir).
See the Publishing chapter in the manual for more details.
Solution using org-export
Since org-attach-expand always expands the file to an absolute pathname, we need to modify it to optionally return a relative pathname (in particular, we want it to return a relative pathname when it is called from org-attach-expand-links, but not in any other case). So we add an optional argument to it:
#+begin_src elisp :results drawer
  (defun org-attach-expand (file &optional convert-to-relative)
    "Return the full path to the current entry's attachment file FILE.
   Basically, this adds the path to the attachment directory. If optional
   argument `convert-to-relative' is non-nil, then return path relative to
   `default-directory'."
    (let ((filepath (expand-file-name file (org-attach-dir))))
      (if convert-to-relative
          (dired-make-relative filepath)
        filepath)))
#+end_src

The advantage of doing it this way is that every call is of the form (org-attach-expand file) with just one argument, i.e. the optional argument is nil and it does not affect how the function works. We will only change one call site, the one in org-attach-expand-links, which will now look like this:
#+begin_src elisp :results drawer
  (defun org-attach-expand-links (_)
    "Expand links in current buffer.
  It is meant to be added to `org-export-before-parsing-hook'."
    (save-excursion
      (while (re-search-forward "attachment:" nil t)
        (let ((link (org-element-context)))
    (when (and (org-element-type-p link 'link)
           (string-equal "attachment"
                 (org-element-property :type link)))
      (let* ((description (and (org-element-contents-begin link)
                   (buffer-substring-no-properties
                    (org-element-contents-begin link)
                    (org-element-contents-end link))))
         (file (org-element-property :path link))
         (new-link (org-link-make-string
                ;; only difference is the following two lines
                ;; (concat "file:" (org-attach-expand file))
                (concat "file:" (org-attach-expand file 'convert-to-relative))
                description)))
        (goto-char (org-element-end link))
        (skip-chars-backward " \t")
        (delete-region (org-element-begin link) (point))
        (insert new-link)))))))
#+end_src


This is identical to the original except for the commented-out line which is replaced by a two-argument call to org-attach-expand.
Evaluating the two code blocks will redefine the two functions and then you can export with C-c C-e h h and look at the output file in the current directory.

As always thank you @NickD !!!.  Your answer provides so much insight !
